# Which one is a noun phrase?

Tags: noun-phrases

> **The guy who is standing over there** is my father

> **The guy standing over there** is my father

Which bolded one is the correct noun phrase?

Comment: They're both correct. Why do you think one is wrong?

Comment: I just thought phrase doesn't suppose to have verb/subject. Isn't "is" there a verb?

Comment: Yes, "is" is a verb in the first sentence, and yes, it needs a subject. The *relative pronoun* "who" is the subject of "is", so it's good grammar.